# Calculation for View Matrix in C++ DirectX 9

Tags: c++, matrix, directx-9

I'm trying to create a first-person shooter camera for my DirectX game. But I'm struggling in trying to get my view matrix right. At the moment I have only got a triangle to display on the screen, but when I rotate the camera and move forward it seems like the triangle is rotating around the camera instead. Here is the code I have done for the Camera Class

**Camera.h**

```
#pragma once

#include"Window.h"
#include"Matrix.h"
#include "Vector3.h"

class Camera
{
public:
    Camera();
    Camera(float pitch, float yaw, Vector3 position);
    ~Camera();

    void Update();

    D3DXMATRIX BuildViewMatrix();

    Vector3 GetPosition() const { return position; }
    void SetPosition(Vector3 val) { position = val; }

protected:
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    Vector3 position;
};
```

**Camera.cpp**

```
#include"Camera.h"
Camera::Camera()
{
    yaw = 0.0f;
    pitch = 0.0f;
}

Camera::Camera(float pitch, float yaw, Vector3 position)
{
    this->pitch = pitch;
    this->yaw = yaw;
    this->position = position;
}

Camera::~Camera()
{
}

void Camera::Update()
{
    pitch = min(pitch, 90.0f);
    pitch = max(pitch, -90.0f);

    if(yaw < 0)
        yaw += 360.0f;

    if( yaw > 360.0f)
        yaw -= 360.0f;


    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_W))
    {
        D3DXMATRIX translateMat;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translateMat, position.x, position.y, position.z);

        D3DXMATRIX rotationMat;
        D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotationMat, D3DXToRadian(yaw));

        D3DXMATRIX forwardMat;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&forwardMat, 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

        D3DXMATRIX transformMat = translateMat * rotationMat * forwardMat;

        position.x = transformMat._41;
        position.y = transformMat._42;
        position.z = transformMat._43;

        std::cout << "X: " << transformMat._41 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Y: " << transformMat._42 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Z: " << transformMat._43 << std::endl;
    }
    else if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_S))
    {
    D3DXMATRIX translateMat;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translateMat, position.x, position.y, position.z);

    D3DXMATRIX rotationMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&rotationMat, D3DXToRadian(yaw));

    D3DXMATRIX forwardMat;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&forwardMat, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f);

    D3DXMATRIX transformMat = translateMat * rotationMat * forwardMat;

    position.x = transformMat._41;
    position.y = transformMat._42;
    position.z = transformMat._43;

    std::cout << "X: " << transformMat._41 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y: " << transformMat._42 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Z: " << transformMat._43 << std::endl;
    }


    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_Q))
    {
        yaw = yaw - 1.0f;
    }

    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_E))
    {
        yaw = yaw + 1.0f;
    }
}

D3DXMATRIX Camera::BuildViewMatrix()
{
    D3DXMATRIX translationMat;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translationMat, (position.x * -1.0f), (position.y * -1.0f), (position.z * -1.0f));

    D3DXMATRIX yawMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&yawMat, D3DXToRadian((yaw * -1.0f)));

    D3DXMATRIX pitchMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationX(&pitchMat, D3DXToRadian((pitch * -1.0f)));

    D3DXMATRIX viewMat = pitchMat * yawMat * translationMat;

    return viewMat;
}
```

I'm using `device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &camera->BuildViewMatrix());` to send the view matrix to directX. What exactly am I doing wrong? Please help

***UPDATE:***

I have change the code and tried to use the `D3DXMatrixLookAtLH` function (doesn't use the Camera at all), but this time, it doesn't do anything - the triangle stays in the same position no matter how I change the LookAt parameter on the function. Here is the code for it:

```
void Renderer::Render()
{
    device->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(40, 40, 40), 1.0f, 0);

    device->BeginScene(); //Must be used as it tells DirectX we're starting to draw stuff.

    D3DXMATRIX worldMat;
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&worldMat, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &worldMat);

    D3DXMATRIX viewMatrix;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &viewMatrix, 
                        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -100.0f, 1000.0f), //position
                        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), //Look at
                        &D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &viewMatrix);
    //device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &camera->BuildViewMatrix());

    D3DXMATRIX projMatrix;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( &projMatrix,
                                D3DXToRadian(45),
                                (float)width/(float)height,
                                1.0f,
                                10000.0f);
    device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &projMatrix);

    device->SetFVF(VERTEXFORMAT);
    device->SetStreamSource(0, vertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(VERTEX));
    device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);

    device->EndScene(); //Thank you for waiting, I have finished drawing stuff on the screen, please handle the rest Mr DirectX.

    device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be translationMat * pitchMat * yawMat?

Comment: Silly me, I should test it out and see

Comment: fixed part of the problem, but not all

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my machine set up to test this, but I think you are missing the part where you translate the camera to 0,0,0 then rotate it and then move it again to the original position.

Comment: @pedrom so in other words, my view matrix isn't set to be identity in the beginning which may cause this problem?

Comment: Sorry ... I didn't realize that you have a BuildViewMatrix method which is actually doing what I proposed... I don't quite understand your update() method then, it should as simple as update the positions but you are applying some rotation over there too. Have you considered to use the helper functions D3DXMatrixLookAtLH or D3DXMatrixLookAtRH to calculate your view matrix instead? Here there is an example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206342(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Pedrom Updated my code, please see the Updated section of my question.

Comment: @Danny Well you are not updating the position on the view matrix, so it makes sense that it is not moving. What if you try to update the eye vector ("D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, -100.0f, 1000.0f), //position") with a variable that you would change in the update method?

Comment: @pedrom Sorry, I think you're misunderstanding. I am not trying to move the camera/view matrix at all. Instead, I am trying to ROTATE it (sorry for not being clear). I have tried to enter `D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` and `D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)` for the "LookAt" parameter, but it is showing exactly the same result i.e: not rotating when it should.

Comment: @Pedrom P.S. I think I should also mention that I have no problem with changing the position, it's just the LookAt(rotation) bit :P. Any help on that will be great :P

Comment: @Danny There is an implicit rotation when you use the lookat vector, which in this case (in theory) should be just the normalized triangle position. Do you say that when you play with that still you don't see any change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem, the matrices I've calculated isn't correct as well as the view matrix. the fixed it by adding the following codes:

**Camera.h**

```
#pragma once

#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx9.lib")
#include<d3dx9math.h>

#include"Window.h"

class Camera
{
public:
    Camera();
    Camera(float pitch, float yaw, D3DXVECTOR3 position);
    ~Camera();

    void Update();

    D3DXMATRIX BuildViewMatrix();

    inline D3DXVECTOR3 GetPosition() const { return position; }
    inline void SetPosition(D3DXVECTOR3 position){ this->position = position;}

protected:
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;

private:
    D3DXVECTOR3 xAxis;
    D3DXVECTOR3 yAxis;
    D3DXVECTOR3 zAxis;
};
```

**Camera.cpp**

```
#include"Camera.h"
Camera::Camera()
{
    yaw = 0.0f;
    pitch = 0.0f;
    roll = 0.0f;
}

//yaw = head twist
//pitch = head tilt
Camera::Camera(float pitch, float yaw, D3DXVECTOR3 position)
{
    this->pitch = pitch;
    this->yaw = yaw;
    roll = 0.0f;
    this->position = position;

    xAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    yAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    zAxis = D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

Camera::~Camera()
{

}

void Camera::Update()
{

    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_Q)){
        yaw -= 1.0f;
    }
    else if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_E)){
        yaw += 1.0f;
    }

    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_Z)){
        pitch += 1.0f;
    }
    else if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_X)){
        pitch -= 1.0f;
    }

    pitch = min(pitch, 90.0f);
    pitch = max(pitch, -90.0f);

    if(yaw < 0.0f)
        yaw += 360.0f;

    if( yaw > 360.0f)
        yaw -= 360.0f;


    D3DXMATRIX yawMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&yawMat, &yAxis, D3DXToRadian(yaw));
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&zAxis, &zAxis, &yawMat);
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&xAxis, &xAxis, &yawMat);

    D3DXMATRIX pitchMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&pitchMat, &xAxis, D3DXToRadian(pitch));
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&zAxis, &zAxis, &pitchMat);
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&yAxis, &yAxis, &pitchMat);

    D3DXMATRIX rollMat;
    D3DXMatrixRotationAxis(&rollMat, &zAxis, D3DXToRadian(0.0f));
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&xAxis, &xAxis, &rollMat);
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&yAxis, &yAxis, &rollMat);

    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_W))
    {
        position = position + (zAxis * -1) * 10.0f;
    }
    else if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_S))
    {
        position = position + zAxis * 10.0f;
    }

    if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_A))
    {
        position = position + xAxis * 10.0f;
    }
    else if(Window::GetKeyboard()->KeyDown(KEYBOARD_D))
    {
        position = position - xAxis * 10.0f;
    }

    yaw = 0.0f;
    pitch = 0.0f;
    roll = 0.0f;
}

D3DXMATRIX Camera::BuildViewMatrix()
{
    D3DXMATRIX viewMatrix;
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&viewMatrix);

    viewMatrix._11 = xAxis.x;
    viewMatrix._21 = xAxis.y;
    viewMatrix._31 = xAxis.z;

    viewMatrix._12 = yAxis.x;
    viewMatrix._22 = yAxis.y;
    viewMatrix._32 = yAxis.z;

    viewMatrix._13 = zAxis.x;
    viewMatrix._23 = zAxis.y;
    viewMatrix._33 = zAxis.z;

    viewMatrix._41 = D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &xAxis);
    viewMatrix._42 = D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &yAxis);
    viewMatrix._43 = D3DXVec3Dot(&position, &zAxis);

    return viewMatrix;
}
```